# Issue with displaying images in Compose when using Coil library with Persian filenames

Tags: android, kotlin

I use Coil to display images in Compose, but when the file name is in Persian along with Persian numerals, the image is not displayed.

```
val a = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
    model = selfUser.imageUrl,
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    onSuccess = {
        Log.d("mohaTest", "HeaderAvatar:onSuccess")
    },

    onError = {
        Log.d("mohaTest", "HeaderAvatar: ${it.result.throwable}")
    }
)
```

error :
HeaderAvatar: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x62a at 21 in content-disposition value: attachment;filename="تست۳_128.jpg"

Comment: Which coil version are you using?

Comment: The version of coil is 1.4.0

Comment: Updating to the latest version should fix this issue, see: https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/1838

Comment: Im sorry, i use 2.4.0 and doesnt fix this issue.

Comment: Latest version is 2.5.0 though.